# “If you are rested I would go,” I urged. Meaning?

Tags: sentence-meaning, american-english, literature

I was trying to translate this sentence but I got confused in this sentence. Does the sentence "I would go" mean something like "I would go if I were you"?

This sentence is from Hemingway's story The Old Man at the Bridge.

This is the next sentence.

> “If you are rested I would go,” I urged. “Get up and try to walk now.”
>
> “Thank you,” he said and got to his feet, swayed from side to side and then sat down backwards in the dust.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More like "I would recommend that you go" or "I think you should go" than
"I would go if I were you."

The use of "urged" suggests the former meaning.

Translating Hemingway I would probably try to mimic

> “If you are rested you should go,” I urged.

word for word with short words. Avoid anything like the three syllable "recommend".

Answer (score 5):

You are correct, "I would" is a shortening of "if I were you I would." This is a less common sense of the word *would*: [OED has it](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/229051) as a verbal phrase, P7 in "will," *v*.1, (marked *colloquial*), defined as 'I advise or recommend you to.' Some other examples:

> I wouldn't do that Sir! (*a common polite way to tell someone to Stop!*) 
> Q: How do I blow up the bridge? B: Well, if you had to, I'd start with the legs... 
> I'd be careful with that photo; you don't want it getting out.

The quote you give is particularly hard to parse because of Hemmingway's very curt style. In this case, the way to read

> “If you are rested I would go.”

is as

> “If you are rested I recommend that you go.”

Comment: While I do not disagree with anything you have said here - it is worth noting that Hemingway, in speech quotation, has a tendency to say it exactly as he hears it. In *For Whom the Bell Tolls* he takes this to the extent where he renders Spanish speech patterns, word order etc, literally into English - and it sounds very strange. I don't think this is what he is doing here, but it does seem as if he is reporting direct speech quite literally.

Comment: I see a striking similarity between "George K." and "James K." :)

Comment: @DialFrost hahah, I noticed that as well :) I assure you we are different people though lol

Comment: A bit suspicious, not gonna lie, considering your answers are well-written and fast (comparable to James_K)! :P And considering James_K went "offline" for awhile when you popped up ... XD